# Ansible ufw module ERROR: Could not find a profile matching 'xxxxx'

Tags: ansible, ufw

I'm working to setup UFW rules via Ansible. I'm able to get it installed, start it and deny everything. I then attempt to allow connections from http, https, and ssh.  All attempts to add the allow for those items are met with errors that look like:

```
failed: [lempy1] (item={u'service': u'http'}) => {"failed": true, "item": {"service": "http"}, "msg": "ERROR: Could not find a profile matching 'http'\n"}
failed: [lempy1] (item={u'service': u'https'}) => {"failed": true, "item": {"service": "https"}, "msg": "ERROR: Could not find a profile matching 'https'\n"}
failed: [lempy1] (item={u'service': u'ssh'}) => {"failed": true, "item": {"service": "ssh"}, "msg": "ERROR: Could not find a profile matching 'ssh'\n"}
```

The entire role looks like this:

#### tasks/main.yml

```
     ---
    - name: Install ufw
      apt: name=ufw state=present
      tags:
        - security

    - name: Allow webservery things
      ufw:
        rule: allow
        name: '{{item.service}}'
      with_items:
        - service: http
        - service: https
        - service: ssh
      tags:
        - security

    - name: Start ufw
      ufw: state=enabled policy=deny
      tags:
        - security
```

Any idea why I wouldn't be able to allow these services? I am able to add the services properly when ssh'ing into the server and running `sudo ufw allow http`, etc.

Comment: Could it be related to the rule name being transmitted with the single quote? I know YAML force you to quote **{{** and **}}** but you could try to replace `'{{item.service}}'` with `"{{item.service}}"` and check the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the [ufw module docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ufw_module.html), the name (or app) parameter uses applications that are registered in `/etc/ufw/applications.d` which have an INI format and look something like this:

```
[CUPS]
title=Common UNIX Printing System server
description=CUPS is a printing system with support for IPP, samba, lpd, and other protocols.
ports=631
```

Normally you can use `ufw allow application-profile` to allow an application defined either in `/etc/ufw/applications.d` or `/etc/services` to open up iptables for things that aren't necessarily defined in `/etc/ufw/applications.d`.

Unfortunately, Ansible's [ufw module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/blob/devel/system/ufw.py#L253) instead builds the ufw command in this format instead:

```
/usr/sbin/ufw allow from any to any app 'application-profile'
```

Which *only* uses the `/etc/ufw/applications.d` list and won't read `/etc/services`.

In your case you could simply specify the ports as these are well known, potentially using a named variable to further explain your Ansible code:

```
- name: Allow webservery things
  ufw:
    rule: allow
    port: '{{ item }}'
  with_items:
    - '{{ http_port }}'
    - '{{ https_port }}'
    - '{{ ssh_port }}'
  tags:
    - security
```

And then define the variables somewhere (such as your role defaults):

```
http_port: 80
https_port: 443
ssh_port: 22
```

As an aside, you might want to notice that I simplified your list of dictionaries with a single key into a simpler straight list which tidies up your task a bit.

Alternatively you could easily template the application profiles using Ansible's [template module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html).

Comment: so I still get the Could not find a profile matching '80'.  Same for all other ports I try and assign.  Error looks like: {"failed": true, "item": 80, "msg": "ERROR: Could not find a profile matching '80'\n"}.  Any ideas?  My task now looks exactly as you've laid it out here.  I'm wondering if a template would be the best thing to do.

Comment: Apologies, that should have been port rather than name. Forgot to edit that when I copied your code into my answer

Comment: Figured that part out fiddling around, thanks again!